# Android Action bar truncated / split within fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-statusbar

My action bar is truncated / split within a particular fragment. I am using roughike-bottom bar and this problem is only occurring in 2/3 fragments that exist for my bottom bar. Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

> ```
> <FrameLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>          android:layout_width="match_parent"
>          android:layout_height="match_parent">           
>
> <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
>
> <FrameLayout
>     android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar" >
>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

Comment: Can you post your xml...lol Not that a screenshot isn't helpful but...

Comment: Just put it up, let me know if you have any ideas... thanks

Comment: @Jaythaking ?    .